# Move to adjacent cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an algorithm that finds a value in a cell, for this case lets say that cell is C10. I need to look next to that in column D for a value, and if that value doesnt match what i need, to go up one cell from that and check for a match, etc. I have this so far:

```
bits = [] 

for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=4,column_offset=3):
    #skip over empty rows
    if row:
        #current cell is in column C
        cell = row[2]
        try:
            #find the lowest address in the excel sheet
            if cell.internal_value == min(address):
                #somehow match up in column d
                for '''loop and search col D''':
                    if str(row[3].internal_value).upper == ('CONTROL 1' or 'CON 1'):
                        #add bits
                        for cell in row[4:]:
                            bits.append(cell.internal_value)    
        #pass over cells that aren't a number, ie values that will never match an address
        except ValueError:
            pass
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

Is there a way to do this? I know the comparison using `row[3]` compares in column D, but if it isnt correct the first time, i dont know how to go up the column. Or in other words, changing the value in `row[value]` moves around the row, and I need to know what value/how to move around the column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bits = []
min_address = False
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=4,column_offset=3):
    c = row[2]
    d = row[3]
    if not d.internal_value: #d will always have a value if the row isn't blank
        if min_address: 
            break #bits is what you want it to be now
        bits = [] #reset bits every time we hit a new row
        continue #this will just skip to next row

    for bits_cell in row[4:]:
        if bits_cell.internal_value:
            bits.append(bits_cell.internal_value)
    if c.internal_value:
        if c.internal_value == min(address):
            min_address = True #we set it to true, then kept going until blank row
```